# How to avoid the appearance of extra top and bottom lines in a table

Tags: tables

I am using iet format. While creating a small table top, mid, bot lines of the table extend to full length of the double column format of the page. How to remove that extra lines. I need only over the content of the table.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\processtable{Efficiency of different inverters\label{tab4}}
{\begin{tabular*}{10pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}\toprule


Efficiency & (\%)     \\\\ \midrule
Fig.9       & 90  \\
Fig.8       & 91    \\
Fig.7       & 93  \\ \botrule
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\botrule`. Also use `\caption` instead of `\processtable`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `\processtable` is intended to create a table that spans the entire page (or column) of text.

The only solution I see (other than using a different class or table construct) is listing the data over several columns instead:

```
\begin{table}[t] 
\processtable{Efficiency of different inverters\label{tab4}}
{
  \begin{tabular*}{10pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllll}\toprule
    Efficiency & (\%) & Efficiency & (\%) & Efficiency & (\%)  \\ \midrule 
    Fig.9 & 90 &
    Fig.8 & 91 & 
    Fig.7 & 93 \\ \botrule 
  \end{tabular*}
}
{} 
\end{table}
```

produces this output:

[image]

The table still spans the entire text area, but it might fit in a 2-column layout.

For reference, here's the `\processtable` definition from the class:

```
\newcommand{\@processtable}[4]{%
\if!#1!%
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%%ADDED ON 21/12/05
\def\fnum@table{}%
\else%
\def\fnum@table{{\tablename}\enspace\thetable}%
\fi%
\let\@makecaption\@tablecaption
\if@rotate
\setbox4=\vbox to \hsize{\vss\hbox to \textheight{%
\begin{minipage}{#4}%
\@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\caption{#1}}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont\sf #2}%
\vskip5\p@\noindent
\parbox{#4}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont\sf #3\par}%
\end{minipage}}\vss}%
\rotr{4}
\else
\hbox to \hsize{\hfil\begin{minipage}[t]{#4}%
%\vskip2.9pt
\@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\caption{#1}}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont\sf #2}%
\vskip5\p@\noindent
\parbox{#4}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont\sf #3\par}%
\end{minipage}\hfil}\fi
}%
```

The fourth argument to `\processtable` should allow you to specify a table width, but I couldn't figure out how to do that and the limited documentation of the cta-author class gives no hints.