# how to remove the extra lines in top and bottom of the table

Tags: tables

I am using `iet` template, but while using that I am unable to make the table width according to the table content.width is coming full length of the double column space.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
{\begin{tabular*}{10pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}\toprule
Efficiency & (\%)     \\\midrule
Fig.       & 92  \\
Fig.      & 99   \\
Fig.     & 100 \\
 \botrule
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am getting an output like this

[image]

But I require a output like this

[image]

What to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! How about replacing `\toprule` and `\botrule` by `\hline`?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the template files?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479198/how-to-avoid-the-appearance-of-extra-top-and-bottom-lines-in-a-table

Comment: @marmot I think the problem is the length of the lines, not their thickness. And I think the problem is the class, because with article I get the desired result.

Comment: Link to the template: https://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the appearance of extra top and bottom lines in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479198/how-to-avoid-the-appearance-of-extra-top-and-bottom-lines-in-a-table)